# how can fix The system cannot find the file specified at visual studio 2022

Tags: c, visual-studio

This is the old picture, not as same as the code below.
[image]

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num, lower, upper;
    double squareroot;
    int square;
    int cube;
    // input value 
    
        do
        {
            printf("the lower value limit is ");
            scanf_s("%d", &lower);
        } while (lower < 0 || lower > 50);

        do
        {
            printf("the upper value limit is ");
            scanf_s("%d", &upper);
        } while (upper < 0 || upper > 50);

        // the formular to find the squareroot, square, cube
        squareroot = sqrt(num);
        square = num * num;
        cube = num * num * num;

            printf("*base number*  ||  *square root*  ||  *square*  ||  *cube*\n");
            printf("*%d*           ||   *%f*      ||   *%ld*      ||  *%ld*\n",
                num, squareroot, square, cube);

        
    
    return 0;
```

The picture says The system cannot find the file specified, and when I try to rebuild the solution, they show me another program issue.
For another program, I was making some changes on there, but when I run it, the thing I changed didn't has a change

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248422/discussion-on-question-by-aster-dis-how-can-fix-the-system-cannot-find-the-file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the comments you posted below the question, the reason for the problem was the following:

You were ignoring the content of the "Output" window, which states that building the executable file has failed.

The "Output" window shows you all the error messages generated by the compiler. You should always read these error messages exactly, and you should not attempt to run the program if compiling failed. Otherwise you may run an old version of the program or get an error message that it cannot find the executable file.

Answer (score 0):

The `<conio.h>` is not present in latest compilers. Your program would throw an error. The `<conio.h>` was discontinued. It was used in MS-DOS compilers long back. Please do add a `}` at the end of the `void main()` function.

Comment: Using `#include <conio.h>` works in Microsoft Visual Studio (not sure about the latest version, though). So I doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: According to the screenshot, there is no `}` missing at the end. Therefore, OP probably just did not paste the code into the question properly. However, the question in its current state is very unclear, because after posting the question, OP edited the question in such a way that the posted code no longer corresponds to the screeenshot.